# How can I get an average of percentages?

Tags: percentage

I can't seem to find an answer to my exact question.

I want find how much on average a stock or the stock market goes up during an up week (or month) and down during a down week (or month). Let's say it goes
up 5% the first week
up 10% the second week
down 20% the third
down 10%
up 15%
up 20%
down 5%.

Can I simply average the percentages? In this case the average for up weeks is (5+10+15+20)/4 = 12.5% and down weeks is (20+10+5)/3 = 11.67%. Or would I need to do something else?

I found a similar question here

[Can percentages be averaged?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144059/can-percentages-be-averaged)

but no one really addressed it.

Comment: First of all, you should rather build some kind of model for this data to have a meaningful estimate rather then blindly average them. As about "averaging" see also: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155817/combining-probabilities-information-from-different-sources/188554#188554

Comment: Take a look at my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/23199/7071).

Comment: You can average anything as part of operational semantics. The question is whether you will be able to interpret the result in a way that will be useful to you or not. So first of all you need to define what is it that you want to achieve, after that we can answer whether arithmetic mean is the operation that will achieve that or not.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with percentages like this, you wouldn't simply take an "arithmetic" average as the result wouldn't be meaningful. Instead, you'll do different kind of averaging. In your example, the arithmetic (regular) mean over all 7 weeks is 1.05 (assuming you add a one to each value). But if you had gained 5% each week, then after 7 weeks, you'd be left with a total return of 40.7%. In reality though, you end up with a total return of 33.2%. So that begs the question, "what average weekly gain would result in a total return of 33.2%?" The answer is 4.19%. The way you figure out this number is simple. You take the "geometric mean" which is defined as $(x_1 \times x_2 \times ... \times x_n)^{1/n}$. In your case, $x_1=1.05$, $x_2=1.1$, etc.

Comment: I am not looking for total return or average weekly gain. What I would like to know is how much can I expect a stock to go up for an up week, and how much to go down for a down week.

Comment: Eliot, it isn't apparent that averaging would tell you that.  For instance, if seven weeks ago the market changed by $-99\%$ and then by $+100\%$ each of the next six weeks, it would *still* be down by $36\%$--but there are few averaging methods indeed that would tell you the average of the changes $-99, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100$ is $-36$!  This is what lies behind the comment made by @Cagdas.

Comment: Ok I didn't catch that when I first read your question. I think the best way to do this is with a simple modification similar to what you did but instead using the harmonic mean. The average "up-week" would then be $(1.05 \times 1.10 \times 1.15 \times 1.20)^{1/4} = 1.124$. You'd have to really stretch to give this a good interpretation though.

Comment: Thanks. It could have practical application. Let's say historically a stock has 33% down weeks and 67% up weeks. Let's also say you decide to buy call options on the stock. Knowing how much you can expect it to go up or down would give you an indication on how much to bet each week (with all the caveats about the past not predicting the future, etc).

Comment: @jjet What you have there is the geometric mean.

Comment: Whoops, thanks for pointing that out. I even looked it up to make sure I wouldn't mix the two up but then I still wrote it down wrong.

Comment: @jjet the geometric mean has a natural interpretation: it is the *constant* rate which, if experienced for each period, would produce the same net gain that was actually observed.

Comment: @whuber yep, that's essentially what I noted in my original answer. However, the geometric mean *conditional on positive observations* is much harder to interpret meaningfully. There's no guarantee that a positive observation will occur so it's not clear what the value of this conditional mean is.

Comment: I don't understand what you might mean by "positive observation."  Changes in prices will be no less than -100%. Thus all the numbers involved in the geometric mean are strictly positive--remember, you have to add $1$ to each of the changes here.

Comment: @whuber please read my previous comments. I did add 1 to each of the values. I'm using "positive observation" to refer to what Eliot is calling "up-weeks." I believe he and I are on the same page.